# Open source command-line tool to access Exchange 2007 inbox?

Tags: email, exchange-2007, command-line-interface, open-source

I'm looking to write a script (running on linux) that connects to an Exchange inbox (as me) and downloads messages.  Is there any open source software out there to support me?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your Exchange server support "standard" protocols like POP3 or IMAP, or does it only support Outlook clients?

Comment: Sadly outlook only :-(

Comment: What you will want to look for is a MAPI command-line client then since it doesn't support POP or IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

the openchangeclient cli tool does that. Check the screencast: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1ul95_openchangeclient-screencast_tech

The instructions on how to create a mapi profile: http://tracker.openchange.org/projects/openchange/wiki/HowTo_Setup_OpenChange_Client

It's still beta software, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything open source to do that, as Exchange native protocols are Microsoft proprietary, so implementing something like this would be quite difficult.

But you can script almost *anything* Exchange-related using PowerShell... why is it not enough for your needs?!?

Comment: I don't have Windows...

Comment: What about a Windows virtual machine with Exchange Management Tools installed?

Comment: Actually, the protocols have been opened up and are free to use for open source projects.  http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/

Answer (score 0):

Is WebDAV available on your exchange server? It is on most, unless explicity disabled I believe. If it is, then I'm sure there's a library that will allow you to do this with WebDAV.

You can check by going to http://SomeExchangeServer/exchange/

**Edit**: A quick search brought up this tool that might serve the purpose that you need, if WebDAV is enabled: http://www.saunalahti.fi/juhrauti/index.html